# Coding style - keep parentheses on the same line or new line?

Tags: python, formatting, coding-style, readability

Suppose you are calling a function, where there's clearly a need to break down the statement into few lines, for readability's sake. However there are at least two way to do it:

Would you do this:

```
return render(request, template,
              {
                'var1' : value1,
                'var2' : value2,
                'var3' : value3
               }
             )
```

Or would you rather do that:

```
return render \
(
    request, template,
    {
        'var1' : value1,
        'var2' : value2,
        'var3' : value3
    }
)
```

Or, please suggest your own formatting. Please also list reasons why would you use a particular formatting and what's wrong with the other one.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd probably do:

```
return render(
    request, 
    template,
    {
        'var1' : value1,
        'var2' : value2,
        'var3' : value3
    }
)
```

I would keep the bracket on the same line, so that searches for `render(` work. And because I find it clearer. But I'd put all the arguments on new lines.

Comment: excellent point on searching for "render("

Comment: +1 Interesting. I've never thought of this style.

Answer (score 11):

Python's official [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests the first one.

Answer (score 9):

I would do:

```
vars = {
    'var1' : value1,
    'var2' : value2,
    'var3' : value3,
}
return render(request, template, vars)
```

Comment: +1, most elegant of the approaches suggested.

Comment: +1 Just because you *can* do it all in one statement doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 2):

The second one looks like it escaped from a C[#+]* program. Backslash line continuation is ugly, prone to trouble with trailing space, and there's no excuse to use it when you've got () or [] to use.

Comment: +1  never use backslash, there is always a better option (continuation inside (), [], {})

Comment: from __future__ import braces

Comment: Perhaps you meant `from __future__ import braces`. `from SOhelp import backticks`